# PowerPoint VBA to delete all comments

Tags: powerpoint, comments

I have some VBA code that automates a number of slide changes ready for me to PDF the sides. I'd like to add a line in to delete all comments from the sides.

Seems simple but have had no luck in finding this anywhere. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job for current versions of PPT. Versions prior to 2007 handled comments differently; I *think* this should still work with older presentations but you'd have to test for yourself if that's an issue.  And MS is liable to make changes to the commenting mechanism at any time, so who knows what might or might not work in future.  But for now:

```
Sub DeleteComments()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oCom As Comment
    Dim x As Long
    
    With ActivePresentation
        For Each oSl In .Slides
            For x = oSl.Comments.Count To 1 Step -1
                oSl.Comments(x).Delete
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```